# How to solve browser cache and service worker issue

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, mean-stack, browser-cache, angular-service-worker

I have two websites with the same domain, the first one (which is the old one also) is developed using MEAN Stack, we were using it for years. We had enabled service worker of Angular.
Now after years we developed the new version of website and replaced Angular with Nuxt. Last week launched the new website.

Both websites are hosted in AWS cloud.

The old website main url was [www.jobs.af](http://www.jobs.af) and we redirected jobs.af (without www) to [www.jobs.af](http://www.jobs.af). But the new version url is jobs.af (without www) and we are redirecting [www.jobs.af](http://www.jobs.af) to jobs.af (without www).

Now everything is work, except caching issue of old visitors, when they open the site it still shows the old version.

I'm seeking for a way to handle this issue, most users can't or not want to clear their browser cache, is there any way to fix this.

Thanks.